# Trouble with caching and 3 wp_query

Tags: wordpress, caching

In my custom theme in WordPress I have created a front-page.php. There I have three WP_Query's. The first one just takes a custom post type.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => array( 'frontpage_element' ),
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // DISPALY A PICTURE
    endwhile;

    // Reset postdata
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

The second is the default Loop.

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        the_title();
        the_content();

    endwhile; 

    // Reset postdata
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

The third WP_Query shows the first 6 post entries of a category.

```
$options = get_option('custom_theme_options');
$categories = implode("," , $options['catprojectlayout']);
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
       'paging'     => 'projectpage',
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'posts_per_page'     => '6',
       'post_status'        => 'publish',
       'cat' => $categories,
       'cache_results' => false
 ), $atts );

 $paging = $atts['paging'];
 unset( $atts['paging'] );

 if( isset($_GET[$paging]) )
    $atts['paged'] = $_GET[$paging];
 else
    $atts['paged'] = 1;

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $atts );
$pagination_base = add_query_arg( $paging, '%#%' );

if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); 
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile; endif; 

echo paginate_links( array(
    'type'      => '',
    'base'      => $pagination_base,
    'format'    => '?'. $paging .'=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, $custom_query->get('paged') ),
    'total'     => $custom_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => '<div class="prevbtn"></div>',
    'next_text' => '<div class="nextbtn"></div>',
    'show_all' => true
));
```

The code works, but I have troubles with caching. When I add a new Post to the defined category, the second WP_Query was not updated (I think because of browser caching).

I think I have the code done like is defined in [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

It should be work like this: When I add a new post in the defined category, a User browse to the front-page, the site must be reloaded from server (because in the third WP_Query there is a new entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is ulikely to be browser caching as browsers tend to store style sheets and images page content is normally re-interpreted each time the page is loaded incase it has changed.

It is more likely to be either cashing on the server or another 3rd party service such as Cloud flare which store the page appearance for a period of time to save regenerating the same wedge of dynamic page controls over and over.

WP_Engine hosting has it's own caching that can be cleared through the installs dash board, Cloud flare allows cache to be cleared per URL and plugins... well these are all different, check if there are any plugins that control caching and either turn them off whilst you are making a change or clear their cache.

Comment: Yes, I think it was a Browser caching, because when I reload the site (not just browse to the navigation, but hit F5 to reload), the site was loading correctly. Is there a way to force the browser cache to reload?

Comment: Normally holding ctrl and pressing F5 will force the new styles and images to be pulled down again... Or you could set a website header to tell the browser not to cache files but this would depend on the webserver being used

Comment: Yes, that's clear. But I search for a way, where I can force to reload by the user. I think the website header was not right way, because the site just have to reload when I have changed someting, not every time.

Comment: I have found my mistake. In .htaccess I had a generally caching für 35 days activ:

Comment: `<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 35 days"
</IfModule>`

Comment: When I remove these lines, the site was reloading correctly when somethin was changed.